# How to port grpc helloworld(CPP) example on yocto

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, yocto, grpc

Hey i am trying to port the helloworld, cpp based demo for [gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp/helloworld) on yocto pyro on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for target arm, . But i am getting the error.

**protoc -I ./ --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/home/admin/BUILD/tmp/sysroots-components/x86_64/grpc-native/usr/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin hello.proto**

**/home/admin/BUILD/tmp/sysroots-components/x86_64/grpc-native /usr/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin: error while loading shared libraries:libprotoc.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

**--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 127.**

**Makefile:55: recipe for target 'hello.grpc.pb.cc' faile**

So can anyone suggest the steps to solve this error.

Please find the  helloworld.bb file.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Hello world"  
SECTION = "Hello world"  
LICENSE = "CLOSED"  

S = "${COREBASE}/../../../src_dir/hello"  
B = "${S}"  

inherit externalsrc  
EXTERNALSRC_pn-hello = "${S}"  
EXTERNALSRC_BUILD_pn-hello = "${B}"  
EXTERNALSRC_SYMLINKS_pn-hello = ""  

DEPENDS = "grpc-native protobuf-native protobuf-c gflags c-ares protobuf-c-native openssl"  

PR = "r1"  

PARALLEL_MAKE =""  

TARGET_CXX_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"  


do_compile() {  
 oe_runmake  
}  


ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"  
FILES_${PN} = "/*"
```

Please find the makefile for it.

```
CXX = arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a8 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed --sysroot=/home/admin/BUILD/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/hello-demo/0.1.0-r1/recipe-sysroot


CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),Darwin)
LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib  `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc`\
       -ldl
else
LDFLAGS +=  -L/home/admin/BUILD/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/hello-demo/0.1.0-r1/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgrpc++_reflection -Wl,--as-needed\
       -ldl

endif
PROTOC = protoc
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN = grpc_cpp_plugin
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH ?= /home/admin/BUILD/tmp/sysroots-components/x86_64/grpc-native/usr/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin

PROTOS_PATH = ./

vpath %.proto $(PROTOS_PATH)

all: hello_client hello_server

hello_client: hello.pb.o hello.grpc.pb.o hello-client.o
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@


hello_server: hello.pb.o hello.grpc.pb.o hello-server.o
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@


.PRECIOUS: %.grpc.pb.cc
%.grpc.pb.cc: %.proto
    $(PROTOC) -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-  grpc=$(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH) $<

.PRECIOUS: %.pb.cc
%.pb.cc: %.proto
    $(PROTOC) -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --cpp_out=. $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.pb.cc *.pb.h hello_client hello_server
```

Please find the my [grpc_1.8.5.bb](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/grpc/grpc_1.8.5.bb?h=master) file.

Comment: You need to add some details on how you use Yocto, which version you use, which target board you aim. Maybe add the recipe that generates this error. You can also add the full log via pastebin.

Comment: post your recipe hello.bb for grpc then we can help you

Comment: Maybe add `inherit cmake` and `DEPENDS = "grpc"`. You will probably need to patch Makefile and cmake files to be compatible with cross-compilation. You can take example on [grpc](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/grpc/grpc_1.8.5.bb?h=master) recipe and its patches.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has nothing to do with the gRPC example, looks like there is an issue with protoc installation script on Linux - it doesn't update dynamic libraries bindings. 
Try to run "ldconfig" from root. And run "protoc" after it, without any arguments.